# Can anybody ID this ship silhouette?

Tags: spaceship, object-identification

[image]

Been driving myself and a group of friends absolutely crazy.

Comment: looks like the ship from galaga (gaming.se's site icon)

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Yes. It would be nice to see the rest of the panel, not just a crop.

Comment: Agree. Would like to see full image.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Original image is from here http://www.othertees.com/design/13136

Comment: @Nephrited - I posted a new question to ID all the ships. Great find, BTW. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133742/54605

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is a Starfighter from the [*Buck Rogers in the 25th Century*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Rogers_in_the_25th_Century_(TV_series)) TV series.

[image: fighter]

Comment: Fantastic. Couldn't find any hint of what it could be online. Will mark as the answer once the time restriction elapses!

Comment: Yah, AI image search has a long, long way to go.

Comment: Just FYI: these ships are classified as "Starfighter". and the reason the profile is slightly different is that the wing edge retracted to the thrusters.

Comment: @KerrAvon - reminds me of the toy one I had as a kid; retractable wings, although I'm sure the wings on it were orange rather than white & green as shown in the picture above...