# What is the ID of all these ships?

Tags: spaceship, object-identification

Based on [this question asking to identify the silhouette of Buck Rogers' star fighter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133621/54605), someone posted a link to pic of the larger collage of ships the question was based on.

[image]

What is the ID of all these ships? Some are quite easy of course, like the Millennium Falcon, USS Enterprise and the TARDIS. But I'm not sure of all of them.

Can someone put numbers on the ships to make the identification easier?

Comment: I spy... Starbug from Red Dwarf, an A-wing, an X-wing... And that one just under the falcon looks familiar but I can't place a name. i really REALLY want to say E-Wing though

Comment: I think the one under the Falcon is a Battlestar Galactica fighter. And the big one on the bottom left is Cocharan's first warp drive ship (ST).

Comment: If got Star Wars (x3), Battlestar Galactica (x2), Red Dwarf, Buck Rodgers, Aliens, Firefly, Star Trek, Dr Who & Futurama so far. I'm not sure of the one next to the Enterprise, though.

Comment: @TheBloodyPoet - the ship next to Enterprise is an alien craft from Independence Day most likely - http://independenceday.wikia.com/wiki/Attacker

Comment: seems this should be a Community answer :)

Comment: @iMerchant Huh, I would have put the bottom left one as Galactica, not the Phoenix, since Cochrane's ship only has one link to the nacelles each -- shown [here](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/9/99/Phoenix_space.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100605052029&path-prefix=en)-- this one has three, as (*Classic*) Galcactica does...

Comment: @BMWurm - Oh yeah. You're probably right. I guess that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @Valorum - and I think I need about 900 more rep to do it :D

Comment: No Moya?! No Farscape-1?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

This ships depicted above are

1 - [U.S.S. Planet Express Ship](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c1/Futurama_Planet_Express_spaceship.jpg) (Futurama)

2 - [Viper Mk II](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Viper_Mark_II) (Battlestar Galactica Reimagined)

3 - [Starbug](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/reddwarf/images/2/2c/RedDwarfStarbug.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070516032055) (Red Dwarf)

4 - [Thunderfighter](http://buckrogers.wikia.com/wiki/Thunderfighter) (Buck Rogers)

5 - [UD-4L Cheyenne Dropship](https://youtu.be/gXSuYpaFd10?t=1m17s) (Aliens)

6 - [Serenity](http://talkingcomicbooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/serenity_wide.jpg) (Firefly)

7 - [Battlestar Galactica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica_(fictional_spacecraft)) (BSG ToS)

8 - [X-Wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X-wing_starfighter) (Star Wars)

9 - [TARDIS](https://advancedgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/1493_Tardis_46.jpg) (Doctor Who)

10 - [A-Wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/RZ-1_A-wing_interceptor/Legends) (Star Wars)

11 - [Attacker](http://independenceday.wikia.com/wiki/Attacker) (Independence Day)

12 - [USS Enterprise NC-1701](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhoxn.jpg) (Star Trek - J.J. Abrams version)

13 - [Millennium Falcon](http://screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/millennium-falcon-space.jpg) (Star Wars)

Comment: that's actually a good catch on the Enterprise being JJ-verse

Comment: How can you tell the difference between the old vs new Battlestar Galactica ships (2, 7)?

Comment: @iMerchant You can easily find top-down silhouettes of all the vipers. I was really into to the new BSG, though, so it was easy to catch.

Comment: @CreationEdge - So both ships are from the 2003 reboot then?

Comment: @iMerchant I didn't even look at that one earlier. No, it's the original. The original has a flatter back end, and 3 connectors between the ports and the main body as opposed to 2 on the newer model. There are other differences, but those are most obvious.